# Removing strings from column

Tags: string, perl

I need to remove specific strings from a table which looks something like this:

```
1->KOM0001 column2 column3...
2->KOM0002 column2 column3...
.  
10->KOM00011 column2 column3...  
.  
.  
156->KOM0159 column2 column3...
```

and so on. I would like to remove either of these: `KOM000`, `KOM00`, `KOM0`, `KOM` if they appear in the first column and replace them with whitespace. I should use Perl to achieve this (not a must) but I'm the newbiest newbie you can imagine and I'm completely stuck.

I should add that the table is large, it has around 1000 lines and more than 100 000 columns.

Unfortunately, my problem is not over with this, but this is a necessary first step so I won't make my question any longer.

Comment: When you say "table", do you mean a DB table?  Have you solved the problem of getting the data out of the DB table and into some kind of Perl data structure?  Or, is the data really in a file, with some kind of separator between the fields?

Comment: Can you provide the data exactly as it will need to be parsed through?

Comment: I`m sorry, by table I meant a .txt file with columns separated by spaces. File is huge, more than 1 GB.

Answer (score 1):

You could clarify this a lot, but assuming it's a file:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\d+->\K(KOM0{0,3})/q{ }x length($1)/e' file
```

Finds your string near the start of a line and replaces each character with a space.

Comment: Nice one! Shouldn't the space replacement be in double quoutes?  (Like: `'s/^\d+->\K(KOM0{0,3})/" " x length($1)/e'`) I get an error from bash using your syntax..

Comment: good eye.  Changed the space to `q{ }` instead so a windows user could still use the one-liner without having to change code inside the eval.

Comment: I forgot to add that my operating system is ubuntu. Thank you for your effort, this code looks simple and elegant. Unfortunately, I get an error message

Comment: Message: Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "q{ }xlength"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "q{ }xlength"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @user3562272 I think you need to add a space after the `x` in `xlength`, like `x length`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
awk '{sub(/KOM0*/,"",$1)}1' file
```

Comment: I tried it, but the file is too big, awk can`t handle it (or I don`t know how to make it work with huge files).

Comment: @user3562272 I recommend the solution of Miller, since it does exactly what you are asking for. However, this solution might also do what you intend to do. It should at least be able to handle the file size. How did you run the command? You might want to redirect the output to another file instead of printing to standard output.

Comment: I ran it with redirection to output file, but, unfortunately, the file is just too big. I get message: awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767

Comment: @user3562272 Then you probably have many fields on each row. In order to prevent `awk` doing field splitting for each row you could try replace `$1` with `$0`.